# Highlight count with date on jQuery UI calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I'm trying to implement jquery ui calendar for my event section which is working fine no doubt but I've one custom requirements in that calendar I wanted to highlight no of events also on particular that for example there's 2 events on 21st jan and 3 on 25th jan then it will show bit highlight to those dates with count.

Is it possible with jquery ui

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#event').datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `beforeShowDay`, a jQuery UI Datepicker Widget Option.

A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:

- `[0]: true/false` indicating whether or not this date is selectable
- `[1]`: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or `""` for the default presentation
- `[2]`: an optional popup `tooltip` for this date

The function is **called for EACH DAY in the datepicker** before it is displayed.

---

For your Problem : **Working solution.**

```js
var highlightdates = ["2016-1-21", "2016-1-25"];

$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(),
      d = date.getDate(),
      y = date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(y + '-' + (m + 1) + '-' + d, highlightdates) != -1) {
      return [true, 'css-class-to-highlight', 'Get the count on Tooltip'];
    }
    return [true];
  }
});
```

```css
.css-class-to-highlight a {
  background-color: green !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  color: White !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">


<p>Date:
  <input id="datepicker1" type="text">
</p>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/3849/)

Reference: [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow)